# how to add some conditional code for redirect to page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Confirm-user.aspx` in asp.net bound to master page. The Confirm-user page is in folder(Manage_pages). I have the sidebar in master page and use this code for list all page that user can access:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>title</h2>
            <ul>
               <% foreach (DAL.Page page in pageList)
               {%>
                   <% Response.Write("<li><a href="+page.PageAddress+">"+page.PageName+"</a></li>"); %>
               <% }%>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click on Confirm-user page link I go to this page successfully:

```
http://localhost:2112/Manage_pages/ConfirmUser.aspx
```

But when I click on link again it does not work and go to:

```
http://localhost:2112/Manage_pages/Manage_pages/ConfirmUser.aspx
```

Please help me!

Comment: Change to `<a href="/+page.PageAddress+">"+page.PageName+"</a>`

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: Make sure that your `page.PageAddress` property returns an address which starts with **`/`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<a href='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/ConfirmUser.aspx")%>'>text</a>
```

the `"~/ConfirmUser.aspx"` could be `"~/Manage_pages/ConfirmUser.aspx"` if `Manage_pages` is your intended sub folder but not your application name

Comment: Hi. +page.PageAddress+ is method that I call it from DAL layer

Comment: nothing different, replace text with <%=page.PageAddress%>

Comment: Hi. where do I replace the code(<%=page.PageAddress%>)  with :my code  Response.Write("<li class=\"cat-item\"><a href="+pageList[i].PageAddress+">"+pageList[i].PageName+"</a> </li>");

Comment: <li><a href="+ResolveClientUrl("~/"+page.PageAddress)+"    i think you need do more search for these basic grammar questions

Comment: Hi. thanks a lot Ray H. it works successfully. it was helpful. merci.

Comment: Response.Write("<li class=\"cat-item\"><a href=" + ResolveClientUrl("~/" + pageList[i].PageAddress) + ">" + pageList[i].PageName + "</a></li>");